# Ubunto/Python/Apache - Print lines

Tags: python, apache, printing

I have a python script and I want to print different elements in different lines. It works well on anaconda, however when I integrate it in a server and run it through apache, everything gets printed together.

With anaconda:

a

b

c

d

In apache:

abcd

How can I get the first result in apache?

The code in the script is simple:
for element in list:
    print(element)

Comment: Have you tried modifying your print statement to be ```print("%c\n",element)```?

Comment: I solved it by adding <br>, but I will try that suggestion as well. Thanks!